# RxJS SwitchMap Error when Piping HTTP Call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to use a switchMap operator to perform some operations in my angular service after making an HTTP call, however it is throwing an error every time and NOT performing the http call at all, and giving a very vague error response [image]

I have a component which calls my service like so:

```
this.authService.login$(userRegistration).subscribe(result => {
// Doing things here
});
```

The authservice call looks like the following:

```
login$(userRegistration: UserRegistrationRequest): Observable<AuthResult> {
        return this.http.post<AuthResult>(url, userRegistration)
        .pipe(
            switchMap(result => {
                if(result.errors || result.errors.length !== 0) {
                    throw(result.errors);
                }

                // do things and then
                return of(result);
            }),
            error => {
                throw(error);
            }
        );
    }
```

This causes the http post to never get fired off, and immediately errors out with the image above. If I remove the switchMap, return just the observable from the service and then subscribe to it in the component, the call succeeds.

Is there something I am missing here? I am relatively new to rxjs so I am not sure if I am misunderstanding something, but any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
I am also able to move the switchMap into the component, do what I need and then call a subscribe at the end and it works fine. Is this the better practice overall?

Comment: add return here `return throwError(...`

Comment: You are catching and rethrowing the error which causes the issue.

Comment: I tried changing it to remove throwing the error completely and it is still not firing the HTTP call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error()` isn't a valid operator in RxJS to include inside `pipe()`, instead you want to use `catchError()` to handle specific error cases. However looking at your example, you don't need to use it since Angular will catch any errors thrown from your HTTP observable.

Additionally, you don't need to use switchMap because you're not relying on another observable. Just use the `map()` operator and return `result` instead of `of(result)`.

```
login$(userRegistration: UserRegistrationRequest): Observable<AuthResult> {
  return this.http.post<AuthResult>(url, userRegistration)
  .pipe(
      map(result => {
          if(result.errors || result.errors.length !== 0) {
              throw(result.errors);
          }

          // do things and then
          return result;
      })
  );
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you!